# Proof question, inequalities

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Please, I should verify if is truly each supposition,
knowing that (a+b)>(d+c), a>b  and c>d

1. a>c
2. a>d
3. b>c
4. b>d

That's a problem from my calculus question list. I really need help.

I tried thought induction, with no success.

Comment: I made an edition

Comment: @JulianaVilei, What have you tried?

Comment: @lulu But a must be greater than d. (Option 2)

Comment: @Zenix  That appeared in an edit after my comment (which is no longer applicable so I will delete it).

Comment: The question is somewhat better post edit but it is still not clear.  Are you assuming all four of those points?  If so, then yes you can deduce that $a+b>c+d$ from those four assumptions.  Or were you asking something else?

Comment: @lulu, knowing that $(a+b)>(d+c), a>b$ and $c>d$, it asks which of options 1,2,3 or 4 is true.

Comment: @Atticus  Ah, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Option 2 is true

Option 1 counterexample: $$a=4,b=3,c=5,d=1$$
Option 3 counterexample: $$a=4,b=3,c=5,d=1$$
Option 4 counterexample: $$a=5,b=1,c=3,d=2$$

Option 2 proof: (where n and m are positive)
$$(a+b)>(c+d)$$
$$(a+a-n)>(d+m+d)$$
$$2a>2d+m+n$$
$$2a>2d$$
$$a>d$$

Comment: thank you very much